# How to properly insert some special characters like ¤ to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, character-encoding

I have an Oracle database. I have to execute some insert scripts that fill a `NVARCHAR2` column. The insert statements include some special character like ¤

```
Insert into myTable (column1, column2) values(1, 'ABC-XYZ-SET-00985203-INS-01_2_10 | (100-BASE¤BASE ART¤3) | (100-SHELL¤SHELL ART¤1) |');
```

When I run the query all the special  character is replaced with **¿** symbol

Database NLS parameters are as follows:

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET        UTF8                                                            
NLS_CHARACTERSET              WE8ISO8859P1
```

I've the special character multiple times repeated in a string.
What should I do for inserting the character I mentioned above **¤** appropriately?

Comment: Which character? The generic currency symbol, or just a way to represent the ASCII special characters (below 32)? Note: it is also important to check where you check the results: not all console and programs supports UTF-8, so maybe you get the correct result, but the console is not able to display it

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I wish to insert the generic currency symbol. Also I checked the results in Notepad++ where the source string was displayed properly but the record fetched from DB had another symbol `¿`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to set also NLS_LANG on your client that supports unicode characters.
Then you can use `N'` nchar literals: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-192417E8-A79D-4A1D-9879-68272D925707

```sql
Insert into myTable (column1, column2) 
values(1, N'ABC-XYZ-SET-00985203-INS-01_2_10 | (100-BASE¤BASE ART¤3) | (100-SHELL¤SHELL ART¤1) |');
```

Notice `N` before `

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to insert non-ASCII characters might be to use the [`UNISTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UNISTR.html#GUID-AAF757DB-6E5D-4548-9E36-6B36BB0BD83E) function. Using the Unicode encoding value instead of the actual character is less convenient, but also less likely to be misinterpreted by whatever future programs run your code.

```
Insert into myTable (column1, column2) values
(
    1,
    'ABC-XYZ-SET-00985203-INS-01_2_10 | (100-BASE'||unistr('\00A4')||'BASE ART'||unistr('\00A4')||
    '3) | (100-SHELL'||unistr('\00A4')||'SHELL ART'||unistr('\00A4')||'1) |'
);
```